# Merging PDFs with different orientations with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I have two PDF files with different orientations (first document is A4 format and the second A4 landscape).
I want to merge them but I need to preserve the original orientation of each page.

I tried with the rotation with this code:

```
  float width = pdfImportedPage.Width;
  float height = pdfImportedPage.Height;

  if (width > height)
  {
      PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(documentPage);
      pageDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(270));
  }
```

After the rotation I call the AddPage method like this:

```
copy.AddPage(pdfImportedPage);
```

But the result is an A4 format document with the second part with the text that goes out of the page. For me is good if the text in the second part is horizontal but I need that also the orientation of the page will be as the original document (horizontal).

I'm using iTextSharp version 5.5.13.

Comment: If you are using `PdfCopy` you'll get the orientation of the original pages. If you are using something else or need to compose the pages we'll need more information.

Comment: No, I'm not using PdfCopy. The object "copy" in the code is of type PdfSmartCopy. Which information do you need? Thanks

Comment: Sorry Paulo, the problem was in another part of the code when I add the page numbers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered that the problem was in another part of the code, after that, when I add the page number.
By the way, a good way to preserve the page orientation is to use the SetPageSize and the NewPage methods, like this piece of code:

```
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{   
    copy.RotateContents = true;
    doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(page));
    doc.NewPage();
    importedPage = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, page);  
    copy.AddPage(importedPage);
}
```

Comment: *"By the way, a good way to preserve the page orientation is to use the SetPageSize and the NewPage methods"* - If you are working with `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy`, those instructions should make no difference at all. If they did, that would be a bug.

Comment: yes, the problem wasn't using PdfSmartCopy or PdfCopy, the problem was in another part of the code where I add the page number